# Component unit testing with @Input with service observable subscription

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I try to test(Jasmine/Karma) a component with an @Input which has subscription to service Observable and it's own property using combineLatest and have this error:

```
*TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.*
```

My code looks like this:

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service {

  private _servicePropertySub = new BehaviorSubject<[]>([]);
  public get servicePropertyObs (): Observable<[]> {
    return this._servicePropertySub .asObservable();
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
//...
@Component({
  //...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
private _componentProp = BehaviorSubject<[]>([]);
public get componentPropObs (): Observable<[]> {
        return this._componentProp.asObservable();
      }

public sum = 0;

@Input()
  public set myInput(value: V) {
    if (v) {
       combineLatest([
            this.service.servicePropertyObs,
            this.componentPropObs 
          ]).subscribe(([one, two]) => {
            this.sum = one + two;
        });
    }
  }

 constructor(private service: Service) {}


//...
```

Numbers in Observables are only for this example.

I want to test this component with @Input but I always have an error about undefined (error above) observable. I guess this is because I create spy for the service. How should this test been created in this case with using service in Input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I'll try to ignore the fact that you are subscribing in an input setter.. and that this subscription is even not completing, thus creating a serious memory leak. The reason you are getting that error is because your spy does not have `servicePropertyObs` property. Better would be to just use a mock provider and attach spies to anything there. So in your test code, you need to add the following provider:

```js
{ provide: Service, useValue: { servicePropertyObs: of(1) } }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and additional comments to my code!